# Change the background image of body if user gives link

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I've created a form to store the url of the background picture of a user if they want to change it from the default image. I'm using the gon gem to make it available to Javascript. I'm trying to make it work so that if a user has a link in their background_picture database column it should be applied to the body's background-image element and for those who havent it should have the default image.

I've managed to change the background-image of the user who has done the form but for the other users its not showing the default one. This is what I did to get it to work on the user with the link in the database.

index.html.erb

```
<% if current_user.background_picture != :null %>
  <% @gon.backgroundPicture = current_user.background_picture %>
<% end %>

$(document).ready(function (){
  if(gon.backgroundPicture !== "") {
      var background = gon.backgroundPicture;
      document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + background + ")";
    };      
});
```

I'm getting this error in the console if I log in as another user,, everything works normally except the default background-image is not there

```
Started GET "/null" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-04-14 02:07:04 +0100
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/null"):
```

My question is basically how can i get it to display the default background-image as it is in the css file ifthe user's background_picture field is empty?

Comment: Why not just make that picture the default but with a style of `visibility:hidden` and "reveal" it in your script when you would otherwise substitute the `gon.backgroundPicture`?

Comment: I've tried adding various else statements to my if statement but none of them worked, could your answer elaborate please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your if statement `if(gon.backgroundPicture !== "")`, if `gon.backgroundPicture` is `undefined`, it will evaluate to `true`, which I don't think is what you want.

You could change the if statement in the javascript or you can set a default value in your view.

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
  if(gon.backgroundPicture) {
    var background = gon.backgroundPicture;
    document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + background + ")";
  };      
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the whole script inside the if block and change the condition to check for the presence of the image.

```
<% if current_user.background_picture.present? %>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + <%= current_user.background_picture %> + ")";
  });
<% end %>
```